# open vm tools fails to customize guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vcenter, vmware-tools, pyvmomi

I am trying to deploy a cent-os 7 VM on a vcenetr from pyvmomi python library and then before powering on the VM I am trying to setup static IP and DNS for the VM.

VM creation goes fine , but guest customization fails, givimg following error:

**Customization of the guest operating system 'rhel6_64Guest' is not sup
ported in this configuration. Microsoft Vista (TM) and Linux guests with Logical
Volume Manager are supported only for recent ESX host and VMware Tools versions
. Refer to vCenter documentation for supported configurations."

faultCause =

faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) []

uncustomizableGuestOS = 'rhel6_64Guest'

Now this customization problem goes away if the VM is just rebooted once. After that we can do the guest customization. 
But this reboot takes around 30 seconds of time and for  our case , we need to get VMs up and running faster than this time.

Any body who faces similar problem and has some context on it will be very helpful.
Also I don't understand how rebooting the VM solves this problem.

Please share your thoughts even if you don't have exact solutions .

Comment: One observation I have is that vCeneter does not show open-vm-tools version unless we power-on the machine at least once. So may be vcenter can not work with open-vm-tools unless it knows the version of  it in the guest OS. and because of that it requires VM to power on at least once.

Answer (score 0):

On further Investigation I found that open-vm-tools does not work until the VM is powered on atleast once.
When Machine is powered on , the HOST system detects the open-vm-tools running on guest OS , and from there on open-vm-tools works.

So open-vm-tools can not be used for initial provisioning as it will just not work at the start up.

Cloud-init is the alternative solution which should be used for initial provisioning.